# What resources should I use to learn to develop apps for Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

I just made up my mind that I want to learn how to develop apps for Ubuntu Linux, using Quickly, and its tools (PyGTK+, Glade, etc.) Is there any tutorials or resources that you can recommend to me, aside from the ones at developer.ubuntu.com, that will help me learn to use these applications? I've looked all over the place, but there just doesn't seem to be a lot of resources online. I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu is an operating system ,you can choose a variety of programming languages to create programs for ubuntu ,ubuntu suggests pyGTK to create program for it ,but it is partially outdated ,because new ubuntu versions using gtk3 instead of gtk2

Answer (score 1):

I first learned PyGTK using the [official tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/tutorial.html), the examples are quite simple and get complex progressively. I believe it is a nice start to understand the GTK way of writing apps (signals, boxes, widgets and so on).

That is a GTK 2 material, so you might want to take a look at another tutorial about [writing GTK3 apps using Python](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/index.html). [Glade integration](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/builder.html) is also covered.

I'd also recommend understanding how (Py)GTK works before going deep into Glade.